# Permission Denied when i try to get access to /bin/sh/... in apache kafka in docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a docker compoose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper-hostname
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper:2888:3888
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    hostname: my-test-kafka
    container_name: test-kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9999:9999"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,DOCKER://0.0.0.0:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "gratitude-topic:3:1,order-is-processed-topic:1:1:"
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

I want to get access to /usr/bin to use consumer console tool or topics.sh a get error

```
/bin/sh: 1: /bin: Permission denied
```

Whats i doing wrong?

I type first `docker exec -it test-kafka /bin/sh` and then when I try to access any directory, I get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to exec /bin/sh

You should be able to run `docker exec "kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092"` directly

But if wurstmeister containers don't work for you, try other ones.

Also, you do not need `host.docker.internal` as an internal, or advertised listener, and remove hostname from Kafka container